# Mongodb MMS point-in-time restore period

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, mongodb-mms

In MMS backup, we have the option `"Allow point-in-time restores going back 1/2/3/4 days"`, which means MMS wil store oplogs to restore within that number of days.

However, when I tried to restore to a time beyond last 24 hours, I got the error message:

```
"You are attempting to restore to a version no longer accessible for restore. Point In Time 
restores are only available for the last 24 hours."
```

Can anyone confirm that MMS currently support only 24 hours Point In Time restore? If yes, what is the purpose of the option to store oplogs up to 4 days?

Comment: What version of MMS are you using? The configuration setting sounds like On-Prem MMS but the information on 24-hour PIT limitation sounds like Cloud MMS.

Comment: Thanks @Stennie, I am using on-prem MMS v1.4.3.106 and backup agent version 1.5.1

Comment: MMS OnPrem is only provided to MongoDB subscription customers, so you should open a Commercial Support ticket for assistance ;-).